# Number input recognition in python

Tags: python, math, boolean

I'm trying to make a script which asks a maths equation, then the user has to type in what they think answer is and then python would output the answer

However, for some reason python doesn't like raw_input() in correlation with the eval statement.

For example, the code is:

```
print "What's 5+4"
a = raw_input()
print eval('5+4')
```

If I was to type in 10 into var 'a', I'd get this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/W1SVH/Math.py", line 3, in <module>
print eval('5 +4')
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

But if I were to replace raw_input with the number '5', the script looks like this.

```
print "What's 5+4"
a = 9
print eval('5+4')
```

Then it would return 9, hence 5+4=9.

Is there anyway to fix this, so that I can use raw_input() to prompt the user?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use `eval`, and your program can (probably) be modified so it can do what you want without using `eval`. But I'm a bit puzzled: _why_ are you doing `eval('a + 4')`?

Comment: For details about the dangers of `eval` please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: `eval` is a really dangerous statement in any program. If I were to use it then I would only use it during trial and testing while writing code from the Python shell. And by `input()` is the same as `eval(raw_input())`.

Comment: In response to 'PM 2Ring' - The reason that eval is in the code was just another experiment in trying to get it to execute correctly, I was just searching up solutions on the Internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object returned by `raw_input()` is a *string*. You need to convert it to an *integer* before performing arithmetic with it.  You can do this with the `int`  built-in function.

```
print "What's 3+7"
a = int(raw_input())
print eval('a +4')
```

**EDIT**:

As ShadowRanger observes, using `eval` is redundant once `a` is an integer, so you can just let Python evaluate the result:

```
print "What's 3+7"
a = int(raw_input())
print(a + 4)
```

This is not only easier to read, but *safer*.  Using `eval` on input received from a user is dangerous and should be avoided.  A malicious user could enter something that, when evaluated, could cause data loss, or use up your computer's resources.

Comment: Of course, once it's an integer, you can skip the `eval`: `print a + 4`

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger, I've updated the answer to reflect this, and add the obligatory warning against eval-ing user input.