# Python Function returing 12 instances of 1 number rather timesing my input my 12

Tags: python, return-value

So I'm trying to create a function that allows me to times a users input by 12. However, for example instead of doing 12 x 4 = 64 its gives me 4 12s' e.g. 444444444444

Ive already tried using the return function on its own and Ive tried creating a variable.

Options Ive tried are:

```
def cube(num):
    print("answer =")
    return num*12

num1 = input("Enter a number to times by 12: ")
print(cube(num1))
```

and:

```
def cube(num):
    print("answer =")
    answer = num*12
    return answer

num1 = input("Enter a number to times by 12: ")
print(cube(num1))
```

I would expect if input number is 4 i would get 64 but the output is shown as 444444444444

Comment: Compare these in your interpreter: `4 * 12`  and `"4" * 12`.

Comment: The **input** function returns a string. When you apply the * operator to it, it simply duplicates it N times. You need to convert the string to an integer or a float if you wish to interpret * to mean multiplication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number input recognition in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498864/number-input-recognition-in-python); the question talks about `raw_input()` but in this case the two are roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the input is read as a string. If you create string `s = 'foo'` and do something like this `s2 = s*4` then s2 will be equal to `foofoofoofoo`. To fix your problem convert input to `int`. So `answer = int(num)*12)`

Answer (score 0):

When you take in input, you get it as a string first.  When you multiply a string, you’ll get repetitions of that string, which is why you’re getting twelve 4s.

You need to convert that input into a number before multiplying it.

Try:

```
cube(int(num1))
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

The function `input` returns a string, not a number. Multiplying a string by a number repeats the string that many times.

You'll want to convert that string to a number early:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter a number to times by 12: "))
print(cube(num1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`input("Enter a number to times by 12: ")` gets input as string. Python strings allows you to multiply them to a number. The result is a number times repeated string (as you see, `444444444444`). If you want to treat input as number, you should convert it to an integer:

`num1 = int(input("Enter a number to times by 12: "))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the input value to a `float` or `int`. `input` always returns a string.

```
num1 = float(input('Enter a number to multiply by 12: '))
```

This will cause a `ValueError` if you enter something that can’t be converted to a number.

If you need to keep asking for a valid input, I always tend to create a function that does this for me:

```
def float_input(prompt=''):
    while True:
        try:
            return float(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid Input')
```

Now replace the `input` in your code with `float_input`